# Function to play animation based on mouse position not working in Godot

Tags: godot4, topdown

I wrote a code to move the player with wasd but I wanted to change the animation based on where the mouse is pointed to, but when I wrote a function to do that, it only worked for the down and left animations, and when the character moves, the animations stop changing at all.

I used the "get_angle_to()" function and used some if statements to select which animation should be played, the code I used to do this is as follows

```
extends CharacterBody2D

var speed = 300.0
var player_is_walking


func _physics_process(delta):
    var direction = Input.get_vector("left","right","up","down")
    
    if direction.x == 0 and direction.y == 0:
        player_is_walking = false
    elif direction.x != 0 or direction.y != 0:
        player_is_walking = true
    
    velocity = direction * speed
    move_and_slide()

    play_anim()
    
    
func play_anim():
    var angle = get_angle_to(Vector2.ZERO.direction_to(get_local_mouse_position()))
    if player_is_walking:
        if angle > 5.49779 and angle <= 7.06858:
            $AnimatedSprite2D.play("U_Walking")
        if angle > 0.785398 and angle <= 2.35619:
            $AnimatedSprite2D.play("D-Walking")
        if angle > 2.35619 and angle <= 3.92699:
            $AnimatedSprite2D.play("R-Walking")
        if angle > 3.92699 and angle <= 5.49779:
            $AnimatedSprite2D.play("L-Walking")
    else:
        if angle > 5.49779 and angle <= 7.06858:
            $AnimatedSprite2D.play("U_Idle")
        if angle > 0.785398 and angle <= 2.35619:
            $AnimatedSprite2D.play("D-Idle")
        if angle > 2.35619 and angle <= 3.92699:
            $AnimatedSprite2D.play("L-Idle")
        if angle > 3.92699 and angle <= 5.49779:
            $AnimatedSprite2D.play("R-Idle")
```